# On Roshar, can humans have a light eye and a dark eye?

Tags: cosmere, genetics, stormlight-archive

In the *Stormlight Archive* series, there are lighteyes, the ruling class of Alethkar, and darkeyes, mere peasants.

I know that genetics are different in these books from in real life, so here’s my question: Are there any known characters on Roshar who have [heterochromia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochromia_iridum) with a light eye and a dark eye? If so, are they considered lighteyed or darkeyed?

Remember to tag spoilers, please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heterochromia definitely exists sometimes on Roshar.  It seems to occur occasionally when a lighteyed and darkeyed person have a child.

In Words of Radiance we meet Redin. (source with spoilers:)

> https://coppermind.net/wiki/Redin

He is the illegitimate son of a light eyed man and a darkeyed woman.  He does not seem to be considered noble and gets confused reactions from people due to his eyes.

Another example is one of Graves' children.  (This page has general spoilers for Stormlight and possible minor spoilers for other Cosmere works:)

> https://coppermind.net/wiki/Graves

Graves' child was the only one with his wife who was "one-eyed" even though they were a darkeyes and a lighteyes in a relationship.  It's likely not a common occurrence, but we do see a few characters with this.

It's not likely that anyone would see the child as noble, because it is evidence that one of the parents is darkeyed and thus non-noble.  It may also be cultural depending on where in Roshar you are at.

Comment: Redin was Valam's bastard, light eyed man's not woman's.

Comment: @Mithoron Good catch, I hadn't even meant to specify which was which but must have been on autopilot.